# Can I modify a Logistic Regression classifier to out put more than one class based on the probabilty?

Tags: classification, logistic-regression, text-classification

I'm training a Logistic Regression classifier on text data. I found that many of my data points have more than one target class. Is it possible to modify my model to output more than one class based on the data.
I plan to split multi-class data points in my training set into distinct classes(i.e. if one x has 3 classes, I will split that text into three so that each different text has a unique class associated with it). Then when I predict on the test data if I will output n classes such that

> Probability(Class_1)+Probabilty(Class_2)+...+Probabilty(Class_n)>0.95

I will use the prdict_proba method of LogisticRegression for this.
Is it a correct way of doing this?. your help is much appreciated.

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression

Answer (score 1):

We can't use the same data with a different label in the same model.

It will confuse the model.

What you need is multiple models *e.g. OneVsRest strategy. i.e. one for each Class*.

**Little clarification**-

What you are looking for is *Multi-label, not Multi-class*. Please check the internet on this. May read this [*SO Answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42977953/2187625) for a quick understanding.

You can implement an *OneVsRest multi-label* yourself but better use the *Scikit-learn implementation* [*Link*](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html#sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier).

> OneVsRestClassifier can also be used for multilabel classification. To use this feature, provide an indicator matrix for the target y when calling .fit.

What it means is to encode your data in a multi-label format when calling `fit()`.

You may use the `from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer` for this.

```
classif = OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression())
classif.fit(X, Y)
```

Read this [*SO Answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19172087/2187625) for an example.

You may also use a `sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier` wrapper for the same. Check this [*SO Answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62016026/2187625)

Comment: Thanks, @10xAI for your answer. Could you please elaborate on the first sentence "We can't use the same data with a different label in the same model.
It will confuse the model."?

Comment: I meant - Let's take an example,  _Data_1 = [1,2,3], y=CAT, Data_2 = [1,2,3], y=DOG_. Same  X but different Y. What should the model learn ?

Comment: As far as I understand, in multi-class classification, we have n models corresponding to n class with a one-vs-rest approach. So for each x, we get n probabilities. We take the highest probability among them. In an animal classifier, there could be a case where p(Dog)>0.5 and P(Cat)>0.5, but the function returns Dog since p(Dog)>P(Cat). Can I tweak the model to output both Cat and Dog. Are there any pitfalls for this approach?